# JButton cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

Este `JFrame` tiene un `JTextField` que una vez ingresados y dando click en "Aceptar" muestra una tabla con los datos ingresados. El problema es que me da este error en getParent():

> The method getParent() is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.List;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;  
public class Ventana extends JFrame {



    private JTextField txtidCliente;

    private JTextField txtnombreCliente;
    private JTextField txtnumeroCuenta;
    private JTextField txttelefono;
    private JButton btnAceptar;
    private JLabel lblidCliente, lblnombreCliente, lblnumeroCuenta, lbltelefono;

    private Container contenedor;
    private GridLayout cuadricula1;
    public Ventana () {
        super ("CREAR UNA CUENTA EN UN BANCO");
        cuadricula1 = new GridLayout (3, 3, 10, 10);

        lblidCliente = new JLabel("ID CLIENTE:");
        lblnombreCliente = new JLabel("NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE:");
        lblnumeroCuenta = new JLabel("NUMERO DE CUENTA:");
        lbltelefono = new JLabel("NÚMERO DE TELEFONO:");


        Object [] array = {"ID CLIENTE", "NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE", "NUMERO DE CUENTA", "TELEFONO"};
        JTable tabla = new JTable (new Object[][]{} , array);
        JScrollPane panel_tabla = new JScrollPane ();
        DefaultTableModel modelo_tabla = new DefaultTableModel (null, array);

        txtidCliente = new  JTextField(15); 
        txtnombreCliente = new  JTextField(45);
        txtnumeroCuenta = new  JTextField(15);
        txttelefono = new  JTextField(15);

        JButton btnAceptar = new JButton("ACEPTAR");

        contenedor = getContentPane();
        contenedor.setLayout(cuadricula1);
        contenedor.add(lblidCliente);
        contenedor.add(txtidCliente);
        contenedor.add(lblnombreCliente);
        contenedor.add(txtnombreCliente);
        contenedor.add(lblnumeroCuenta);
        contenedor.add(txtnumeroCuenta);
        contenedor.add(lbltelefono);
        contenedor.add(txttelefono);
        contenedor.add( btnAceptar);    

        btnAceptar.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JTable tblDatos = new JTable();
            DefaultTableModel modelo=(DefaultTableModel) tblDatos.getModel(); 

            //Sección 2
            Object [] fila=new Object[4]; 

            //Sección 3
            fila[0]=txtidCliente.getText(); 
            fila[1]=txtnombreCliente.getText(); 
            fila[2]=txtnumeroCuenta.getText(); 
            fila[3]=txttelefono.getText(); 

            //Sección 4
            modelo.addRow(fila); 

            //Sección 5
            tblDatos.setModel( modelo); 


            tabla.setModel(modelo_tabla);
            panel_tabla.setViewportView(tabla);
            getContentPane().add(panel_tabla);
            panel_tabla.setBounds(12, 350, 513, 250);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(700,150);
            setVisible(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(this.getParent());
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu problema es la última línea del código que has puesto:

```
setLocationRelativeTo(this.getParent());
```

Está claro que debe darte error porque si te fijas estás dentro de la definición de tu `ActionListener` anónimo.
Para hacer lo que quieres debes hacer una de estas dos opciones:

1. Sacar esa línea de código fuera y antes de esa definición y luego pasárselo para que la uses dentro
2. Tomar el elemento sobre el que quieres actuar (igual que has hecho con el `TableModel` y modificarlo dentro, pero ten en cuenta que en ese caso te va a pedir que tenga el modificador `final` o sea efectivamente como `final`.